# How to sideload baseline profiles in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, baseline-profile

I read the official docs but just can't get it running.
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles#measuring-baseline

My basline profiles are set up and I have my baseline-prof.txt file in the main folder.

Not sure on how to test it on my device now.

The docs say:

```
Next, let's sideload the Baseline Profile.

Note: This workflow is only supported on version Android 9 (API 28) to Android 11 (API 30).

# Unzip the Release APK first
unzip release.apk
# Create a ZIP archive
# Note: The name should match the name of the APK
# Note: Copy baseline.prof{m} and rename it to primary.prof{m}
cp assets/dexopt/baseline.prof primary.prof
cp assets/dexopt/baseline.profm primary.profm
# Create an archive
zip -r release.dm primary.prof primary.profm
# Confirm that release.dm only contains the two profile files:
unzip -l release.dm
# Archive:  release.dm
#   Length      Date    Time    Name
# ---------  ---------- -----   ----
#      3885  1980-12-31 17:01   primary.prof
#      1024  1980-12-31 17:01   primary.profm
# ---------                     -------
#                               2 files
# Install APK + Profile together
adb install-multiple release.apk release.dm
```

But when I start typing those commants in the Terminal it tells me right away:

```
unzip:  cannot find or open release.apk, release.apk.zip or release.apk.ZIP.
```

I have no clue how to do it and I'm not able to find any other source which explains it

**EDIT**
The docs state: "Note: This workflow is only supported on version Android 9 (API 28) to Android 11 (API 30)."
So I cannot sideload baseline profiles on my Android 12 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 12+ security updates restrict side-loading these, so yes. You cannot, as is clear from the docs.

Here's a handy-dandy Kotlin sample to help you easily, efficiently and seamlessly find out if your version is compatible or not.

```
val android_version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

// Let Kotlin demonstrate 
if (android_version in 9..11)
   print("Side-loading now")
else throw Exception("Oops! Wrong Android!")
```

Issue on `Android 12` -(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232104540)

Issue on `Android 13` -(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232104548)

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently on Android 12+.

If you are trying to see what your app performance feels like for a user download your app from the Play Store, you can tell the Android runtime to fully compile the app which is slightly better than Baseline Profiles by running

`adb shell cmd package compile -m speed -f <YOUR_APPS_PACKAGE_NAME>`

Comment: But forcing AOT compilator with the commant you postet is going to work on Android 12+? Just no baseline-profile sideloading?

Comment: Sir your query has been resolved. My solution is the only answer as of the present Compose.